# Como adicionar hover em ícones próprios do Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para adicionar hover aos ícones do Bootstrap.

Até o momento meu código está assim:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="rgba(194, 56, 58, 1)" class="bi bi-book hover-icon" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
 <path d="M1 2.828c.885-.37 2.154-.769 3.388-.893 1.33-.134 2.458.063 3.112.752v9.746c-.935-.53-2.12-.603-3.213-.493-1.18.12-2.37.461-3.287.811V2.828zm7.5-.141c.654-.689 1.782-.886 3.112-.752 1.234.124 2.503.523 3.388.893v9.923c-.918-.35-2.107-.692-3.287-.81-1.094-.111-2.278-.039-3.213.492V2.687zM8 1.783C7.015.936 5.587.81 4.287.94c-1.514.153-3.042.672-3.994 1.105A.5.5 0 0 0 0 2.5v11a.5.5 0 0 0 .707.455c.882-.4 2.303-.881 3.68-1.02 1.409-.142 2.59.087 3.223.877a.5.5 0 0 0 .78 0c.633-.79 1.814-1.019 3.222-.877 1.378.139 2.8.62 3.681 1.02A.5.5 0 0 0 16 13.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 0-.293-.455c-.952-.433-2.48-.952-3.994-1.105C10.413.809 8.985.936 8 1.783z"/>
</svg>
```

Após algumas tentativas só consegui chegar até aqui com o CSS:

```css
.hover-icon:hover {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='black' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M1 2.828c.885-.37 2.154-.769 3.388-.893 1.33-.134 2.458.063 3.112.752v9.746c-.935-.53-2.12-.603-3.213-.493-1.18.12-2.37.461-3.287.811V2.828zm7.5-.141c.654-.689 1.782-.886 3.112-.752 1.234.124 2.503.523 3.388.893v9.923c-.918-.35-2.107-.692-3.287-.81-1.094-.111-2.278-.039-3.213.492V2.687zM8 1.783C7.015.936 5.587.81 4.287.94c-1.514.153-3.042.672-3.994 1.105A.5.5 0 0 0 0 2.5v11a.5.5 0 0 0 .707.455c.882-.4 2.303-.881 3.68-1.02 1.409-.142 2.59.087 3.223.877a.5.5 0 0 0 .78 0c.633-.79 1.814-1.019 3.222-.877 1.378.139 2.8.62 3.681 1.02A.5.5 0 0 0 16 13.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 0-.293-.455c-.952-.433-2.48-.952-3.994-1.105C10.413.809 8.985.936 8 1.783z'/></svg>") ;
 }
```

O resultado foi esse antes e depois do `hover`:

[image: Antes do hover]

[image: Depois do hover]

A intenção era pintar de preto após o hover como o próprio código CSS propõe, porém a impressão que dá é que apenas está adicionando a mesma svg(pintada de preto) por cima.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poderia fazer de uma maneira, que afetaria todos os svg's da página, alterar a propriedade `fill` toda a vez que acontecer um `hover`.

Exemplo:

```css
svg:hover {
  fill: rgba(0,0,0,1); /* preenche com a cor "black" */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Projeto</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="32"
        height="32"
        fill="rgba(194, 56, 58, 1)"
        class="bi bi-book hover-icon"
        viewBox="0 0 16 16"
      >
        <path
          d="M1 2.828c.885-.37 2.154-.769 3.388-.893 1.33-.134 2.458.063 3.112.752v9.746c-.935-.53-2.12-.603-3.213-.493-1.18.12-2.37.461-3.287.811V2.828zm7.5-.141c.654-.689 1.782-.886 3.112-.752 1.234.124 2.503.523 3.388.893v9.923c-.918-.35-2.107-.692-3.287-.81-1.094-.111-2.278-.039-3.213.492V2.687zM8 1.783C7.015.936 5.587.81 4.287.94c-1.514.153-3.042.672-3.994 1.105A.5.5 0 0 0 0 2.5v11a.5.5 0 0 0 .707.455c.882-.4 2.303-.881 3.68-1.02 1.409-.142 2.59.087 3.223.877a.5.5 0 0 0 .78 0c.633-.79 1.814-1.019 3.222-.877 1.378.139 2.8.62 3.681 1.02A.5.5 0 0 0 16 13.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 0-.293-.455c-.952-.433-2.48-.952-3.994-1.105C10.413.809 8.985.936 8 1.783z"
        />
      </svg>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ou para seções específicas da página, alterando determinado svg de acordo com a seção:

```css
.menu > svg:hover {
  fill: rgba(0,0,0,1); /* preenche com a cor "black" para svg's dentro do menu */
}

.body > svg:hover {
  fill: rgb(135, 16, 172); /* preenche com a cor "purple" para svg's fora do menu */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Projeto</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="menu">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="32"
          height="32"
          fill="rgba(194, 56, 58, 1)"
          class="bi bi-book hover-icon"
          viewBox="0 0 16 16"
        >
          <path
            d="M1 2.828c.885-.37 2.154-.769 3.388-.893 1.33-.134 2.458.063 3.112.752v9.746c-.935-.53-2.12-.603-3.213-.493-1.18.12-2.37.461-3.287.811V2.828zm7.5-.141c.654-.689 1.782-.886 3.112-.752 1.234.124 2.503.523 3.388.893v9.923c-.918-.35-2.107-.692-3.287-.81-1.094-.111-2.278-.039-3.213.492V2.687zM8 1.783C7.015.936 5.587.81 4.287.94c-1.514.153-3.042.672-3.994 1.105A.5.5 0 0 0 0 2.5v11a.5.5 0 0 0 .707.455c.882-.4 2.303-.881 3.68-1.02 1.409-.142 2.59.087 3.223.877a.5.5 0 0 0 .78 0c.633-.79 1.814-1.019 3.222-.877 1.378.139 2.8.62 3.681 1.02A.5.5 0 0 0 16 13.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 0-.293-.455c-.952-.433-2.48-.952-3.994-1.105C10.413.809 8.985.936 8 1.783z"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="32"
          height="32"
          fill="rgba(194, 56, 58, 1)"
          class="bi bi-book hover-icon"
          viewBox="0 0 16 16"
        >
          <path
            d="M1 2.828c.885-.37 2.154-.769 3.388-.893 1.33-.134 2.458.063 3.112.752v9.746c-.935-.53-2.12-.603-3.213-.493-1.18.12-2.37.461-3.287.811V2.828zm7.5-.141c.654-.689 1.782-.886 3.112-.752 1.234.124 2.503.523 3.388.893v9.923c-.918-.35-2.107-.692-3.287-.81-1.094-.111-2.278-.039-3.213.492V2.687zM8 1.783C7.015.936 5.587.81 4.287.94c-1.514.153-3.042.672-3.994 1.105A.5.5 0 0 0 0 2.5v11a.5.5 0 0 0 .707.455c.882-.4 2.303-.881 3.68-1.02 1.409-.142 2.59.087 3.223.877a.5.5 0 0 0 .78 0c.633-.79 1.814-1.019 3.222-.877 1.378.139 2.8.62 3.681 1.02A.5.5 0 0 0 16 13.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 0-.293-.455c-.952-.433-2.48-.952-3.994-1.105C10.413.809 8.985.936 8 1.783z"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Serviu direitinho mano!! Muito Obrigado...

Comment: Publiquei o feedback ai

Answer (score 0):

A resposta de [Cmte Cardeal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/95771/cmte-cardeal) serviu certinho!!

Vou encaminhar como ficou o código:

```
<li class="nav-item svg-hover">
      <a class="nav-link mr-2" href="#">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="rgba(194, 56, 58, 1)" class="bi bi-chat-dots" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M5 8a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zm4 0a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zm3 1a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2z"/>
          <path d="M2.165 15.803l.02-.004c1.83-.363 2.948-.842 3.468-1.105A9.06 9.06 0 0 0 8 15c4.418 0 8-3.134 8-7s-3.582-7-8-7-8 3.134-8 7c0 1.76.743 3.37 1.97 4.6a10.437 10.437 0 0 1-.524 2.318l-.003.011a10.722 10.722 0 0 1-.244.637c-.079.186.074.394.273.362a21.673 21.673 0 0 0 .693-.125zm.8-3.108a1 1 0 0 0-.287-.801C1.618 10.83 1 9.468 1 8c0-3.192 3.004-6 7-6s7 2.808 7 6c0 3.193-3.004 6-7 6a8.06 8.06 0 0 1-2.088-.272 1 1 0 0 0-.711.074c-.387.196-1.24.57-2.634.893a10.97 10.97 0 0 0 .398-2z"/>
        </svg>
      </a>
    </li>
```

Adicionei uma classe chamada "svg-hover" em todos os icones que queria que tivessem o efeito de hover...
Ai no CSS ficou assim:

```
.svg-hover svg:hover {
fill:rgba(194, 56, 58, 0.75)
}
```

O resultado foi esse:

[image: Antes do hover]

Antes do hover

[image: Depois do hover]

Depois do hover